# I do need some assistance with a creating a loop that displays the information

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to output the all of the information provided but i can only output the final output entered a set of times.I am pretty new to loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int sized = 0;

 //Global array declaration 
 Employee Array [60]:

//Struct declaration
struct Employee
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double salary;
};

//Protype
void Showinfo(Employee);

int main()
{
    //Declaring a variable of type Employee
    Employee Emp;

    cout << "Enter the number of employees you want to enter into the database: ";
    cin >> sized;
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("cls");

    //Getting the name of the Employee
    for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Full name of employee: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, Emp.name);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter age of employee: ";
        cin >> Emp.age;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter salary of employee: ";
        cin >> Emp.salary;
        cout << endl;
        system("cls");
    }

    // To display the elements of the information given
    cout << endl << "Displaying Information." << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++)
    {
        Showinfo(Emp);
    }

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

//To display/showcase the information received
void Showinfo(Employee Emp)
{
    cout << "Name: " << Emp.name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << Emp.age << endl;
    cout << "Salary: " << Emp.salary << endl << endl;
}
```

> The expected outcome is like
>
> Inputs by the user***
>
> Enter the no of information to be stored: 2
>
> Enter Name:ball
>
> Enter age:69
>
> Enter wage:420
>
> Enter Name:Rally
>
> Enter age:42
>
> Enter wage:690000
>
> Expected output: Displaying information
>   ------------------------- Name:ball
>
> age:69
>
> wage:420
>
> Name:Rally
>
> age:42
>
> wage:690000
>
> My output Displaying Information
>
> Name:Rally
>
> age:42
>
> wage:690000
>
> Name:Rally
>
> age:42
>
> wage:690000
>
> So basically my program outputs the final set of information received
>   * Sized number of times

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thats what the `cin.ignore();` right before that call is. It discards the `\n`

Comment: @Yastanub You're right, I didn't read the question properly, sorry.

Comment: It would make sense to replace all the `endl` and even `endl << endl`s by '\n' or "\n\n" repectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single `Employee` instance in your code. Either merge the two loops into one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Full name of employee: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, Emp.name);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter age of employee: ";
    cin >> Emp.age;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter salary of employee: ";
    cin >> Emp.salary;
    cout << endl;
    system("cls");
    // To display the elements of the information given
    cout << endl << "Displaying Information." << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    Showinfo(Emp);
}
```

However, this will interleave user input with the output. Instead you can use a vector:

```
std::vector<Employee> employees;
for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Full name of employee: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, Emp.name);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter age of employee: ";
    cin >> Emp.age;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter salary of employee: ";
    cin >> Emp.salary;
    cout << endl;
    employees.push_back(Emp);
    system("cls");
}

for (const auto& e : employess) {
   Showinfo(e);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without using vectors and array<Employee, sized> Emps; because i the question i am asked to use loops and functions along structures rather than vector or arrays

Comment: @BallRall the first variant does not use a vector, but then you only have a single instance, ie you need to print it before taking input for the next

Comment: i meant to say i have to take all the inputs first and then output them is there a way to do this by just modifying the loop or creating another loop

Comment: @BallRall no, you have to store the input somewhere. If you overwrite it in the next iteration of the loop there is no way to print it later

Comment: Also it's never to early to learn about const correctness: Change `void Showinfo(Employee Emp)` to `void Showinfo(const Employee& Emp)` and use `const auto&` in the for loop.

Comment: @nada you forgot the @, anyhow thanks for reminding me, I considered it, but then forgot to add it

Comment: @nada well only now I noticed that it is passed by value, so it isnt that relevant and a too long detour from the actual question to add it to the answer

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 True, another possibility would be to just use it without explaining it, so OP might go *"Oh what is that '&' and 'const'? I need to learn about this."*

Comment: @nada ok thanks i search it up but is there a way to do it with storing it in arrays rather than using vectors the professor is complaining.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 can i do it storing it in an array

Comment: @BallRall if you mean `std::array` you need to know the size already at compile time. Note that `std::vector` basically **is** a resizable array (and much more). If you are asking for c-style arrays, I would actually suggest you to consult your teacher/tutor becaues c-style arrays are by no means easy to deal with and require thorough studying of intricate details to avoid common pitfalls.

Comment: @BallRall It is a bit controversial whether beginners should start with low-tech such as c-arrays or jump to the fun part of std containers like `std::vector`. I have a strong opinion on that, anyhow, if your teacher thinks it is a good idea to keep you away from `std::vector` then they should provide a solid base for using c-style arrays.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 ok i would do that so that means there is an alternative to vectors by storing it in an array but can i know what is it that you prefer since you said you have a strong opinion on that

Comment: @BallRall vectors are simple c-arrays are difficult.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 ok thanks can i know how to store all these values in the array and then output them the required way and by arrays i meant https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_arrays.htm this . I did not understand what c arrays meant is the link i provided is what c arrays are i searched them and this is what i got  " C-Style array is just a "naked" array - that is, an array that's not wrapped in a class, like this "

char[] array = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

Answer (score 3):

> So basically my program outputs the final set of information received

Because you only define one instance of `Employee`:

```
Employee Emp;
```

and then store your input into that single `Emp`.

You want something more like:

```
cout << "Enter the number of employees you want to enter into the database: ";
cin >> sized;
//Declaring a vector type Employee of size sized
std::vector<Employee> Emps(sized);
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need a container with a variable size to store all entered employees.

The more appropriate container in your case is `std::vector`.

Here is a demonstrative program,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Employee
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double salary;
};

std::ostream & Showinfo( const Employee &employee, std::ostream &os = std::cout );

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of employees you want to enter into the database: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    employees.reserve( n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Employee emp;

        std::cout << "Enter Full name of employee: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline( std::cin, emp.name );

        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "Enter age of employee: ";
        std::cin >> emp.age;

        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "Enter salary of employee: ";
        std::cin >> emp.salary;

        std::cout << '\n';

        employees.push_back( emp );
    }    

    // To display the elements of the information given
    std::cout << "\nDisplaying Information.\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------\n";

    for ( const Employee &emp : employees ) Showinfo( emp );

    return 0;
}

//To display/showcase the information received
std::ostream & Showinfo( const Employee &emp, std::ostream &os )
{
    os << "Name: "   << emp.name   << '\n';
    os << "Age: "    << emp.age    << '\n';
    os << "Salary: " << emp.salary << '\n';

    return os << std::endl;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the number of employees you want to enter into the database: 2

Enter Full name of employee: ball

Enter age of employee: 69

Enter salary of employee: 420

Enter Full name of employee: Rally

Enter age of employee: 42

Enter salary of employee: 690000


Displaying Information.
--------------------------------
Name: ball
Age: 69
Salary: 420

Name: Rally
Age: 42
Salary: 690000
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you return the stream? I mean its not really enabling chaining here..

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 In this case you can concatenate the function with operators <<.

Comment: ah ok, as in `ShowInfo(emp) << " <-- employee of the month";`, understand